Cant install Ubuntu
Recently I built a pc with a r5 3600 64gb ddr4 3200 ram and an rtx 4070ti super and im trying to run Ubuntu Linux. I get to the screen where it says "try or install" and it looks like this

When I click on any of the options, the screen goes black and just sits there. I tried waiting for an hour and nothing happened. Another thing that happens is I go to pick a boot device and when I click on it the screen goes black with an underscore in the left corner. Someone told me its because nvidia and Linux do not play well together so I will be picking up an rx550 to test it. Any ideas? (ps I am very new to Linux so I got no idea.)

You might find a solution here: My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?

You gave lots of hardware info but failed to say what version of Ubuntu you are trying to install or how you are trying to install it. Did you verify that the ISO is good that you made the boot media from? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

This question is similar to: My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
